# WSO2 API Manager throw Unable to send events to the endpoint errors

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

In our deployment (WSO2 API manager 2.0.0 All-in-One 2 node clustered with separate WSO2 DAS server), had an issue with depsync as the SVN repo was corrupted. The issue has been resolved, however now we are now noticing following error in wso2carbon.log repetitively.

```
[2017-02-08 02:55:43,229] ERROR - DataEndpoint Unable to send events to the endpoint. 
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointException: Cannot send Events
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftDataEndpoint.send(ThriftDataEndpoint.java:83)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpoint$EventPublisher.publish(DataEndpoint.java:330)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpoint$EventPublisher.run(DataEndpoint.java:283)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:129)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.general.ThriftEventTransmissionService$Client.recv_publish(ThriftEventTransmissionService.java:168)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.general.ThriftEventTransmissionService$Client.publish(ThriftEventTransmissionService.java:155)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftDataEndpoint.send(ThriftDataEndpoint.java:76)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:127)
    ... 16 more
```

Hence am not sure if SVN repo corruption is related, however this issue is something we observed since the incident.

Clarification, is this referring to local thrift server:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7611            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1549/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7711            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1549/java
```

or DAS thrift server?

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7612            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1560/java       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7712            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1560/java
```

Both seem to available.

What is the impact of this error to the system?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is data publishing to DAS. Check connectivity from APIM to DAS node. This can happen if the thrift bind IP is different from the IP of the request.

Impact is that data is not published to DAS.

Comment: Thanks. Once I rebooted DAS, the issue is resolved. Please note that it takes few hours once DAS back up for the errors to stop in WSO2 APIM servers.